# How to index a df with a 2D array and lookup for values from another one?

Tags: python, pandas

My inputs are `df` and two arrays :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5']})

indexes = np.array(
    [[1, 2],
    [4, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 0],
    [1, 0]])

values = np.array(
    [[0.012, 0.019],
    [0.009, 0.012],
    [0.019, 0.028],
    [0.042, 0.061],
    [0.009, 0.021]])
```

I'm trying to get the corresponding ids based on the `indexes` array and also at the same time pull up the values.

My code below gives the expected output but not only it gives me warning but it is also very slow on my dataset.

```
wanted = df.copy()
for i, j in enumerate(indexes):
    wanted.at[i, 'list_ids'] = ', '.join(df.iloc[j].squeeze().tolist())
    
for i, j in enumerate(values):
    wanted.at[i, 'list_values'] = np.array(j, dtype='object')
    
print(wanted)

   id   list_ids     list_values
0  id1  id2, id3  [0.012, 0.019]
1  id2  id5, id1  [0.009, 0.012]
2  id3  id1, id2  [0.019, 0.028]
3  id4  id3, id1  [0.042, 0.061]
4  id5  id2, id1  [0.009, 0.021]
```

Do you guys know how to improve it or do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) indexing:

```
df['list_ids'] = df['id'].to_numpy()[indexes].tolist()
df['list_values'] = values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
    id    list_ids     list_values
0  id1  [id2, id3]  [0.012, 0.019]
1  id2  [id5, id1]  [0.009, 0.012]
2  id3  [id1, id2]  [0.019, 0.028]
3  id4  [id3, id1]  [0.042, 0.061]
4  id5  [id2, id1]  [0.009, 0.021]
```

If you want strings, unfortunately you have to loop:

```
df['list_ids'] = list(map(', '.join, df['id'].to_numpy()[indexes]))
df['list_values'] = values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
    id  list_ids     list_values
0  id1  id2, id3  [0.012, 0.019]
1  id2  id5, id1  [0.009, 0.012]
2  id3  id1, id2  [0.019, 0.028]
3  id4  id3, id1  [0.042, 0.061]
4  id5  id2, id1  [0.009, 0.021]
```

Comment: I'm so impressed by your first solution (it's 10 times faster than mine). Thanks my friend.

Comment: @VERBOSE numpy indexing is really much faster than python loops, every time you need to map a large numpy of values with an array/dataframe as input you should check if you can do it with direct pandas/numpy slicing/indexing ;)